# Is there a possibility to add OMR codes to Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Is there any way to add OMR codes for letter inserters onto an Oracle Report?

Dirty tricks or not, any ideas are welcome. So far I was thinking of either drawing the lines and hiding/showing them depending on the page. Either that or creating 16 different images (8 combinations for start and end) -> Explanation: The top 2 represent start and stop, the bottom represents a binary sequence going from bottom to top.

Here is the desired result:

[image: Image showing OMR codes on paper]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was developing such a report (boy, it was ... 15 years ago, I don't remember details any more), I created separate lines. Each of them had its own **Format trigger** which returned TRUE (if that line had to be displayed) or FALSE (if not), based on a function result.

If I remember well,

- the 1st line was always displayed
- the 2nd line represented beginning of "data set" (e.g. 3 papers had to be put into the same envelope, so the 1st of these 3 pages had that line displayed)
- the 3rd line represented end of "data set" (as above; that line was displayed on the 3rd page of that set, which means that these 3 papers were put into the same envelope)
- the next 3 lines were "counters" (binary, of course):

  - no lines = 0
  - only the 1st line = 1
  - only the 2nd line = 2
  - the 1st and the 2nd line = 3
    etc.

  You're having more "counter" lines than I did, but it doesn't matter, the principle is the same.

It worked on both Neopost and Pitney-Bowes machines.

---

P.S. Did you hug your backup today? I just did - found the report that dates back in August 2007. Here's a screenshot which illustrates what I was trying to describe:

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: I actually saw your contribution from 2007 on another website. Yeah, I get that part, I wrote a function that will return '| | | | |' (1 1 1 1 1), based on the page, which I'll print vertically. It'll allow me to adjust the spacing a bit easier as well.

Comment: That would be OraFAQ, I presume :) I hope you'll manage to make it work.

Comment: While we're at it. Do you have an idea how to get the current page number within a repeating frame. Because I'm trying to group them together and it's not always 8 pages.

Comment: Did you try the SRW built-in package? SRW.GET_PAGE_NUM?

Comment: It returns the current number of the page number, instead I want the page number within  a repeating frame. So whilst I have 5 pages, I want them to be numbered 1,2,1,2,3 for example

Comment: Aha. Huh, I'm afraid I wouldn't know, then. What we were printing were "uplatnice" (you're from Slovenia, I hope you understand what it is), and there were 3 of them on each page. I knew how many many of them each customer had so it wasn't difficult to calculate that number. I don't know what kind of info you're printing, but - see if you can "calculate" that number.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm kinda planning to do. We're trying to print "fakture", which are invoices. They can have as many pages as there is items on them. But the catch here is that they can be printed for multiple customers at once, then they are loaded into a letter inserter and inserted into multiple letters.

Comment: Right; that's where "end of set" OMR line says "put those papers into the same envelope". For simplicity, see if you can make the machine "ignore" counter OMR lines (they are used so that it (the machine) knows whether it got all papers it expected (so that no paper was skipped)). What matters in that case are just two lines: start and end of each set. Therefore, maybe you don't really care how many pages / papers there are - you just have to be able to identify the **last** paper.